# Flash AS3 - textInput box @ " keyboard character issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, character-encoding, textinput

this q has already come up before but the answers given didn't help me.

I have text input boxes which display the " symbol in place of the @ and vice-versa.

when i test locally my @ and " are appearing correctly only when i upload to the server does the problem arise.

I read that you can have "Use device fonts" set for text input box. Whis apparently corrects the issue.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/help.html?content=WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7d1e.html

Is there a way to do this for a text input component?

or should i build custom text input boxes?

or is there a third way?

any input is greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using wmode transparent or opaque? there are quite a few bugs and glitches with this wmodes in all browsers, including the change in keyboard configuration... see this:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-105

The only real solution is to use wmode=window (the default behaviour). If you really need the wmode as transparent or opaque (i.e. for overlapping HTML), there is no easy workaround, as it's not only the @ character, but the whole keyboard configuration that gets mixed up.

I would suggest you to **never use wmode transparent or opaque** for anything a bit more complex as a banner, as they are very unpredictable across browsers/systems/moon-alignments, so the testing phase can be a real nightmare...

Comment: It turns out i was being very lazy and stupid. While i believe the bug pointed out above does exist - all i really needed to was to embed the movie correctly - i'd used a very basic embed for test purposes and when i found this method of embedding the movie correctly - http://latrine.dgx.cz/how-to-correctly-insert-a-flash-into-xhtml - my problem dissappeared. Not entirely sure what it was that fixed it but i'm glad that it is working again!

Thanks for your comments folks!

Comment: Altough valid, that's a bit outdated (2006)... you may want to check swfobject: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding the font ?